# shutil.rmtree fails because file has \\?\ in path

Tags: python, windows, delete-directory

I'm writing a Python script that searches an archive folder and deletes backup folders I don't need anymore. This is for Windows.

I'm using

```
shutil.rmtree(myPath, True)
```

to delete my folders. The command is able to delete most of the data but some files are left behind. I checked and they all have \?\ as the start of their path.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Include some sample paths, so we can confirm that they're valid syntax. Check `os.path.exists` on some of the failing files to confirm that they still exist and are accessible.

Comment: The paths all display as \\?\X:\myPath\filename

The files are visible in the file browser but cannot be opened. Using     os.path.exists returns false

Comment: Are they the only ones on drive "X:"? Can you open anything on this drive from Python?

Comment: rmtree was able to delete about 98% of files in each folder. Its only a handful of files that have this issue

Comment: @MichaelS I have removed your "answer". The question body is for the *question*. If you found an answer please post it as such; it is fine to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I couldn't delete the files because the full path was too long. By renaming some of the folders in the path I'm able to access and delete the files as usual.